# Manually reordering variables in a bar plot with r

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I want to manually reorder variables in a bar plot. I did a hopeless attempt for it with `fct_relevel` and it didn't work. What might make this a bit more complicated is that the plot comes from two data frames. Thanks for your help.

Here's the code

```
bind_rows(B = B, C = C, .id = 'id') %>%
  filter(question %in% c("Q1", "Q2")) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(mean, question, fill = id, xmin = mean - sd, xmax = mean + sd, y = fct_relevel(B, C "Q1", "Q2")) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge2", width = 0.5) +
  geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge2(padding = 0.5), width = 0.5) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

Here's the data frames

```
B <- structure(list(question = c("Q1", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12", "Q2", 
"Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9"), n = c(204L, 204L, 
204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L), 
    mean = c(5.22549019607843, NA, 4.95098039215686, 4.39705882352941, 
    5.47058823529412, 5.51470588235294, 4.50490196078431, 4.92647058823529, 
    4.40686274509804, 5.56862745098039, 5.56372549019608, 5.23529411764706
    ), sd = c(1.1524816893289, NA, 1.31214449357814, 1.5422430010719, 
    1.12039650223724, 1.15104553532809, 1.37714471881058, 1.34621721218454, 
    1.30030385262334, 0.871099231072865, 0.830963499839951, 1.36945187401243
    )), row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

C <- structure(list(question = c("Q1", "Q10", "Q11", "Q12", "Q2", 
"Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9"), n = c(13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), mean = c(5.38461538461539, 
4.38461538461539, 4.69230769230769, 4.30769230769231, 5.15384615384615, 
5.38461538461539, 4.76923076923077, 5.30769230769231, 4.53846153846154, 
5.61538461538461, 5.69230769230769, 4.92307692307692), sd = c(1.26085034391223, 
1.44559454541846, 1.03155347127648, 1.60128153805087, 0.898717034272917, 
1.12089707663561, 1.01273936708367, 0.85485041426511, 0.967417922046845, 
1.26085034391223, 0.85485041426511, 1.84668795692624)), row.names = c(NA, 
12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another solution that switches the "B" and "C" bars order, ie setting the factor in reverse order and manually setting the legend.

```
  bind_rows(B = B, C = C, .id = 'id') %>%
    filter(question %in% c("Q1", "Q2")) %>% 
    mutate(id = factor(id,levels = c("C","B")),question=factor(question,levels=c("Q2","Q1"))) %>% 
    ggplot() +
    aes(mean, question, fill = id, xmin = mean - sd, xmax = mean + sd) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge2", width = 0.5) +
    geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge2(padding = 0.5), width = 0.5) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6)) +
    ylab("question") +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("B"="red","C"="green"),labels=c("B","C"))
```

[image: barplot]

Comment: Excellent Rorio, this does the job!

Answer (score 1):

Do you want Q1 to be above Q2? You may use the `fct_rev` function from `forcats` here:

```
bind_rows(B = B, C = C, .id = 'id') %>%
  filter(question %in% c("Q1", "Q2")) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(mean, fct_rev(question), fill = id, xmin = mean - sd, xmax = mean + sd) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge2", width = 0.5) +
  geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge2(padding = 0.5), width = 0.5) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6)) +
  ylab("question")
```

[image]

Comment: ```fct_rev``` is a useful function too. I needed to find a way to determine whatever order and to do it manually, like with ```levels``` as Rorio showed